# Android: Fully Justify Two Buttons

Tags: android-layout

I have a linear layout, with layout parameters of fill parent, and wrap content. The orientation is horizontal.

Inside the linear layout I have two buttons. They appear next to each other on the left hand side.

I would like the two buttons to "fully justify". In other words I want each button to take half the width of the linear layout.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use weights like:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <Button
    android:text="Button1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

 <Button
    android:text="Button2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

define a weight sum for the parent set each children to half

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:weightSum="2">

     <Button
        android:text="Button1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
        android:text="Button2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you definetely don't need to set a weightSum. You could add it, but it's not necessary. In fact: "weightSum defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children"